# Implementation of a coin jar

Tags: c#, interview-questions

> Implement a coin jar in C#. The coin jar will only accept US coinage
>   and has a volume of 32 fluid ounces. Additionally, the jar has a
>   counter to keep track of the total amount of money collected and has
>   the ability to reset the count back to $0.00.

I received the question above from one of the recruiter for initial screening. He asked me to submit code for it, which I did and pasted below.

Please review and show me any improvements that I can make to my code.

```
//Please ignore coins’ volume, as they are not from valid sources.
public interface ICoinJar
{
    void Accept(ICoin coin);

    IVolume TotalVolume { get; }

    ICurrency ActualAmount { get; }

    IVolume ActualVolume { get; }

    void Reset();
}

public interface ICoin
{
    IVolume Volume { get; }

    ICurrency Value { get; }
}

public interface IVolume
{
    long Unit { get; set; }

    double InRelativeMeasure();
}

public interface ICurrency
{
    long UnitPrice { get; set; }

    double InCurrency();
}

/// <summary>
/// For this class, One unit price is equal to One cent.
/// For other
/// </summary>
public class USCurrency : ICurrency
{
    public long UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public double InCurrency()
    {
        return UnitPrice / 100;
    }
}

public class FluidOunces : IVolume
{
    public long Unit
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Considering Unit is 10000 times smaller than one Fluid Ounce.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public double InRelativeMeasure()
    {
        return (double)this.Unit / 10000;
    }
}

public abstract class UsCoin : ICoin
{
    public string Owner
    {
        get
        {
            return "Federal Reserve";
        }
    }

    public abstract IVolume Volume { get; }

    public abstract ICurrency Value { get; }
}

public class Penny : UsCoin
{
    private IVolume volume;
    private ICurrency currency;

    public Penny()
    {
        volume = new FluidOunces();
        volume.Unit = 122;
        currency = new USCurrency();
        currency.UnitPrice = 1;
    }

    public override IVolume Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return volume;
        }
    }

    public override ICurrency Value
    {
        get
        {
            return currency;
        }
    }
}

public class Nickel : UsCoin
{
    private IVolume volume;
    private ICurrency currency;

    public Nickel()
    {
        volume = new FluidOunces();
        volume.Unit = 243;
        currency = new USCurrency();
        currency.UnitPrice = 5;
    }

    public override IVolume Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return volume;
        }
    }

    public override ICurrency Value
    {
        get
        {
            return currency;
        }
    }
}

public class Dime : UsCoin
{
    private IVolume volume;
    private ICurrency currency;

    public Dime()
    {
        volume = new FluidOunces();
        volume.Unit = 115;
        currency = new USCurrency();
        currency.UnitPrice = 10;
    }

    public override IVolume Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return volume;
        }
    }

    public override ICurrency Value
    {
        get
        {
            return currency;
        }
    }
}

public class Quarter : UsCoin
{
    private IVolume volume;
    private ICurrency currency;

    public Quarter()
    {
        volume = new FluidOunces();
        volume.Unit = 270;
        currency = new USCurrency();
        currency.UnitPrice = 25;
    }

    public override IVolume Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return volume;
        }
    }

    public override ICurrency Value
    {
        get
        {
            return currency;
        }
    }
}

public class HalfDollar : UsCoin
{
    private IVolume volume;
    private ICurrency currency;

    public HalfDollar()
    {
        volume = new FluidOunces();
        volume.Unit = 534;
        currency = new USCurrency();
        currency.UnitPrice = 50;
    }

    public override IVolume Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return volume;
        }
    }

    public override ICurrency Value
    {
        get
        {
            return currency;
        }
    }
}

public class Dollar : UsCoin
{
    private IVolume volume;
    private ICurrency currency;

    public Dollar()
    {
        volume = new FluidOunces();
        volume.Unit = 800;                  // just a guess, could not get the real figures....
        currency = new USCurrency();
        currency.UnitPrice = 100;
    }

    public override IVolume Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return volume;
        }
    }

    public override ICurrency Value
    {
        get
        {
            return currency;
        }
    }
}

public class MyCoinJar : ICoinJar
{
    private List<ICoin> coinHeap;
    private FluidOunces totalVolume;
    private ICurrency actualAmount;
    private FluidOunces actualVolume;

    public IVolume TotalVolume
    {
        get
        {
            return totalVolume;
        }
    }

    public ICurrency ActualAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return actualAmount;
        }
    }

    public IVolume ActualVolume
    {
        get
        {
            return actualVolume;
        }
    }

    public MyCoinJar()
    {
        totalVolume = new FluidOunces();
        totalVolume.Unit = 320000;
        Reset();
    }

    public void Accept(ICoin coin)
    {
        if (coin.GetType().BaseType != typeof(UsCoin))
            throw new InValidCoinException("MyCoinJar accepts only UsCoin");
        if (this.TotalVolume.Unit < (this.actualVolume.Unit + coin.Volume.Unit))
            throw new CoinOverFlowException();

        coinHeap.Add(coin);
        actualVolume.Unit += coin.Volume.Unit;
        actualAmount.UnitPrice += coin.Value.UnitPrice;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        coinHeap = new List<ICoin>();
        actualVolume = new FluidOunces();
        actualAmount = new USCurrency();
    }
}

public class CoinOverFlowException : Exception
{
    public CoinOverFlowException()
        : base("Coins overflowed the jar")
    {
    }
}

public class InValidCoinException : Exception
{
    public InValidCoinException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already submitted this?

Comment: you should really try to test the code to make sure that it works before submitting it as a review here.

Comment: you should be consistent with your indentation and formatting. i.e. `public long Unit{get;set;}` should be on one line like the rest, seeing as how there is nothing inside of it. this is for a job interview?  you want it too look professional and consistent even if it is not exactly what they are looking for.

Comment: Maybe a bit over-engineered. I get it that `ICoinJar` might be useful for unit tests, but all those USCoin/Penny/etc. classes seem overkill.

Comment: Also, don't use `double` for currency. Use `decimal`.

Comment: About 10% of the code has to do with the coin jar, which was the whole point.  80% is fluff, and the remaining 10% missed the boat on polymorphism.  More worrying is the client gets to find out the jar is full by getting an exception?  And if it's ok, there's silence?  And where's the unit tests?

Comment: @DeeMac Yes I already submitted this long back...n I din't get any call back so am assuming I made some mistakes in my codes coz of which i got rejected.

Comment: @Malachi I tested the code, working just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I would just do away with a lot of the code. That would include most interfaces and most classes, as they don't really do anything towards solving the task at hand.

Anyway, you have two classes that use integer storage internally, but only expose the value as a double, so there is no advantage in storing it other than as a double.

You can use the constructor to set the value, that way it's not possible to create one without initialising it properly, and you can keep it from being changeable once it's set.

```
public class USCurrency : ICurrency {

    public double UnitPrice { get; private set; }

    public UsCurrency(double unitPrice) {
        UnitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

}

public class FluidOunces : IVolume {

    public double Unit { get; private set; }

    public FluidOunces(double unit) {
        Unit = unit;
    }

}
```

In all your coin classes you repeat the same code for storage and getters, so you can just put that in the base class. Again you can use the constructor to easily initialise the class, and make sure that it's not possible to inherit the base class without properly initialising it.

```
public abstract class UsCoin : ICoin {

    public IVolume Volume { get; private set; }
    public ICurrency Value { get; private set; }

    public UsCoin(double volume, double value) {
        Volume = new FluidOunces(volume);
        Value = new USCurrency(value);
    }

}

public class Penny : UsCoin {

    public Penny() : base(0.0122, 0.01) { }

}

public class Nickel : UsCoin {

    public Nickel() : base(0.0243, 0.05) { }

}

public class Dime : UsCoin {

    public Dime() : base(0.0115, 0.1) { }

}

public class Quarter : UsCoin {

    public Quarter() : base(0.0270, 0.25) { }

}

public class HalfDollar : UsCoin {

    public HalfDollar() : base(0.0534, 0.5) { }

}

public class Dollar : UsCoin {

    public Dollar() : base(0.0800, 1.0) { }

}
```

Comment: thnx man, I was proud with what I have written before..lol..now I know there are lot of things I should brush on.

Comment: This questions was given to test my coding n its style, designing and OOPs skill. Unit test was not required. Still do you think these interfaces was an overkill?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

> ```
> if (coin.GetType().BaseType != typeof(UsCoin))
> ```

does not support multiple levels of inheritance.

try:

```
if(!coin is UsCoin)
```

Comment: I down-voted as this is not a very thorough answer of the style that Code Review encourages. I would recommend that you visit [How to write a good answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center. I encourage you to also review some of the other answers on the site to see what we are about.

Comment: Recent edits by the community have caused me to remove my downvote. It's a much better answer without all the noise.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the good work by @Guffa.  I build upon his answer.  This is not to say mine is more correct.  Rather mine is offered as alternatives to consider.

Anytime I am dealing with currency, I always use `decimal` over `double`.  Since volume is a physical property of a coin, it is proper that it should be a `double`.  Making those changes to the code by @Guffa:

```
public interface ICoin
{
    IVolume Volume { get; }
    ICurrency Value { get; }
}

public interface IVolume
{
    double Unit { get; }
}

public class FluidOunces : IVolume
{
    public double Unit { get; private set; }
    public FluidOunces(double unit)
    {
        Unit = unit;
    }
}

public interface ICurrency
{
    decimal UnitPrice { get; }
}

public class UsCurrency : ICurrency 
{
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; private set; }
    public UsCurrency(decimal unitPrice) 
    {
        UnitPrice = unitPrice;
    }
}
```

No big deal up to now.  But Guffa's classes Penny through Dollar are public classes that while they are derived from UsCoin aren't tightly associated with UsCoin.  What if this app later also needed to have an Australian Dollar?  Would there be a name conflict?

So I decided to borrow a technique from Eric Lippert to have a derived private class within the abstract class that returns public instances of the derived class cast as the public abstract class.  [For more, click here.](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/16/producing-combinations-part-two/)

That enables me to use something like:

```
public abstract class UsCoin : ICoin
{
    public IVolume Volume { get; private set; }
    public ICurrency Value { get; private set; }

    public UsCoin(double volume, decimal value)
    {
        Volume = new FluidOunces(volume);
        Value = new UsCurrency(value);
    }

    // Note derived private class will allow us to return instances of the
    // of that private class but cast as the public abstract class.
    // http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/16/producing-combinations-part-two/
    private class CoinMint : UsCoin
    {
        public CoinMint(double volume, decimal value) : base(volume, value) { }
    }

    public static UsCoin Penny
    {
        get { return new CoinMint(0.0122, 0.01m); }
    }

    public static UsCoin Nickel
    {
        get { return new CoinMint(0.0243, 0.05m); }
    }

    public static UsCoin Dime 
    {
        get { return new CoinMint(0.0115, 0.1m); }
    }

    public static UsCoin Quarter 
    {
        get { return new CoinMint(0.0270, 0.25m); }
    }

    public static UsCoin HalfDollar 
    {
        get { return new CoinMint(0.0534, 0.5m); }
    }

    public static UsCoin Dollar
    {
        get { return new CoinMint(0.0800, 1.0m); }
    }
}
```

So now I would refer to `UsCoin.Dollar` which would not conflict with `AusCoin.Dollar`.  Again, this is just an alternative to Guffa's groundwork.  Something to consider.